# How much extra balance is needed per DataEntry

Tags: operations, data

The documentation for the [`Manage Data`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-data) operation states that:

> An account can have an arbitrary amount of DataEntries attached to it. Each DataEntry increases the minimum balance needed to be held by the account.

What is the additional account balance needed per data entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `DataEntry` increases the required [minimum balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance) by the size of the `base reserve` (currently **0.5 XLM**).

> The minimum balance for a basic account is 2 × base reserve. Each additional entry costs the base reserve. Entries include:
>
> - Trustlines
> - Offers
> - Signers
> - Data entries
>
> For example, an account with 1 trustline and 2 offers would have a minimum balance of (2 + 3) × base reserve = 2.5 XLM.